# How can i query parse data by creation date with swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I want to be able to organize the data i am receiving from parse by creation date, How do i do that?

I looked at the parse docs online, but i could not find anything that said how to query data by creation date. I also saw an answer of stack over flow, but it was in objective-c. Please answer in swift.

Here is the code i am using now to receive my data...

```
  var query = PFQuery(className:"Class Name")
//this is what i tried..
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

//
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                // Do something with the found objects


                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {

                        self.NameArray.insert(object.valueForKey("Name")! as! String, atIndex: 0)
                        self.TextArray.insert(object.valueForKey("Text")! as! String, atIndex: 0)






                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                self.alert("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)", Message: "Make sure you have a secure internet connection")
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                println("Finished importing")

            self.collectionView.reloadData()


            }
        }
```

Comment: what is wrong with this code? It seems that is already ordering by creation date as per query.orderByDescending("createdAt")